# Python dataframe; trouble changing value of column with multiple filters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a large dataframe I took off an ODBC database. The Dataframe has multiple columns; I'm trying to change the values of one column by filtering two other.
First, I filter my dataframe data_prem with both conditions which gives me the correct rows:

```
data_prem[(data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))]
```

Then I use the replace function on the selection to change 'M' value to 'H' value:

```
data_prem[(data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))]['Reinsurer'].replace(to_replace='M',value='H',inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Python warns me I'm trying to modify a copy of the dataframe, even though I'm clearly refering to the original dataframe (I'm posting image so you can see my results).

[dataframe filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th6N5.png)

I also tried using .loc function in the following manner:

```
data_prem.loc[((data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))),'Reinsurer'] = 'H'
```

which changed all rows that fit the second condition (str.contains...), but it didn't apply the first condition. I got replacements in the 'Reinsurer' column for other 'PRODUCT_NAME' values as well.

I've been scouring the web for an answer to this for some time. I've seen some mentions of a bug in the pandas library, not sure if this is what they were talking about.

I would value any opinions you might have, would also be interesting in alternative ways to solving this problem. I filled the 'Reinsurer' column with the map function with 'PRODUCT_NAME' as the input (had a dictionary that connected all 'PRODUCT_NAME' values with 'Reinsurer' values).

Comment: No, I take the data off a server and create an Excel report.

Comment: it looks very strange to me, I don't find any logical mistake in your code.

Comment: Your first example.. `data_prem[(data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))]['Reinsurer'].replace(to_replace='M',value='H',inplace=True,regex=True)` is a clear example of chained indexing. The error is correct. Always use `loc`.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] with some data as text so we can reproduce your problem with `loc`.

Comment: OK, this is really strange. When I was trying to use the `.loc` function before, I wrote it differently than above:

`data_prem[(data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))].loc[data_prem[(data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & (data_prem['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16'))],'Reinsurer'] = 'H' `

Basically, I was using `.loc` on the filtered dataframe. I overcomplicated the code before (though I remember I tried simpler ways as well and had problems with them before I tried the overly complicated one).

Answer (score 1):

Given your Boolean `mask`, you've demonstrated two ways of applying [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). This is the cause of the warning and the reason why you aren't seeing your logic being applied as you anticipate.

```
mask = (data_prem['PRODUCT_NAME']=='ŽZ08') & df['BENEFIT'].str.contains('19.08.16')
```

#### Chained indexing: Example #1

```
df[mask]['Reinsurer'].replace(to_replace='M', value='H', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

#### Chained indexing: Example #2

```
df[mask].loc[mask, 'Reinsurer'] = 'H'
```

#### Avoid chained indexing

You can keep things simple by applying your `mask` once and using a single `loc` call:

```
df.loc[mask, 'Reinsurer'] = 'H'
```